# Start mosquitto broker from java web logic

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mosquitto

Hello I am using `Spring MVC` for application and `mosquitto` broker but sometimes it got shut down unexpectedly I tried to create a logic where I will regularly check the `mosquitto` status with `/etc/init.d/mosquitto status`.

#### I am getting the Response

```
mosquitto (pid 2632) is running...
```

Then I stop `mosquitto` manually using putty and check the status and i got message:

```
`mosquitto is stopped`
```

Then I try to start it from web logic with command `/etc/init.d/mosquitto start` but in response i got message:

```
`Starting Mosquitto MQTT broker[ OK ]`
```

But `mosquitto` didn't start I tried multiple times but no solution

Any suggestion guys?
code i am trying to excecute command is

```
private String executeCommand(String command) {

    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = 
                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                    String line = "";           
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return output.toString();

}
```

and then calling it like

```
String command = "/etc/init.d/mosquitto status" ;
String output = executeCommand(command);
String output2 ="";
if(output.contains("stopped")){
    command="/etc/init.d/mosquitto start";
    output2=executeCommand(command);
}
sendEmail("amit@virtualweb.co.in",output+" "+output2);
            map.addAttribute("msg",output+"  "+output2);
```

or any other alternative

code is ok but problem is command is not executing like when using PUTTY we logged in with username password we are remotely haldling a PC so start command executes as administrator like double click on windows works to start a exe file and from programming logic we didn't do any login so other wise command is executing only start command is not working
command "/etc/init.d/mosquitto status" is running and when mosquitto was on response was ""mosquitto (pid 2632) is running..."" and when it was off response was "mosquitto is stopped" but then i tried to start with "/etc/init.d/mosquitto start" it shows "Starting Mosquitto MQTT broker[ OK ]" but didn't really start it and sometimes Starting Mosquitto MQTT broker[ FAILED ]
or any other alternative aim is i need to make mosquitto on 24/7 and if stop unexpectedly then start it

Comment: no code? config files? errors? stacktrace??

Comment: code is ok but problem is command is not executing like when using PUTTY we logged in with username password we are remotely haldling a PC so start command executes as administrator like double click on windows works to start a exe file and from programming logic we didn't do any login so just trying to examine the problem other wise command is executing only start command is not working

Comment: command "/etc/init.d/mosquitto status" is running and when mosquitto was on response was ""mosquitto (pid 2632) is running...""  and when it was off response was "mosquitto is stopped" but then i tried to start with "/etc/init.d/mosquitto start" it shows "Starting Mosquitto MQTT broker[ OK ]" but didn't really start it and sometimes Starting Mosquitto MQTT broker[ FAILED ]

Comment: you should add this info in the question, what I mean is we don't have enough info to know what is happening to you either an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so it's hard to help you....